# If $f'$ exists on an interval and is not constant, then $f'$ must take on some irrational values.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives

This is from the book Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott under Chapter 5. It was to decide whether the following conjecture is true or false. I think it's true, so here's my attempt of proving it.

The conjecture:

> If $f'$ exists on an interval and is not constant, then $f'$ must take on some irrational values.

Before my proof attempt of the conjecture, I will state (without proof) a Theorem that I will be using.

> Theorem (Darboux's Theorem). If $f$ is differentiable on an interval $[a, b]$, and if $\alpha$ satisfies $f'(a) < \alpha < f'(b)$, then there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ where $f'(c) = \alpha$.

---

*Proof of conjecture:*

Given that $f'$ exists on an interval, say, $[a, b]$ which just means that $f$ differentiable on $[a, b]$. Also, suppose $f'$ is not constant, i.e. we can choose $f'(a) \neq f'(b)$.

Now, take any $x, y \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x) < f'(y)$ and $f'(x), f'(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Consider the number $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) < \alpha < f'(y)$. By Darboux's Theorem, there exists $z \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(z) = \alpha$.

This implies that $f'$ must take some (in fact, all) values between $f'(x)$ and $f'(y)$ which are both rational numbers.

This, thus, implies that $f'$ must take on some irrational values, concluding the proof.

---

Can someone pinpoint anything that might be wrong in this proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your conjecture is an immediate corollary of Darboux's Theorem.

Comment: @ClementYung Sure it is.